# Force user to visit browser and perform dialog action

Tags: jquery, browser, cross-browser

I am trying to implement the server timeout alert in a web application. I followed the instructions given [here](http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/). It works fine. I am looking for a way such that when the timeout dialog box pops up it should redirect the user from whichever window/browser s/he is and perform an action on the dialog box. Any leads are helpful. Thanks :)

Here's my code snippet:

```
<script>
    var myRedirectUrl = '/logout/';
    var idleTime = 5000 //read session timeout value from web.config number of miliseconds until the user is considered idle
    var initialSessionTimeoutMessage = 'Your session will expire in <spanid="sessionTimeoutCountdown"></span> seconds.<br>Click on <b>OK</b> to continue your session.';
    var sessionTimeoutCountdownId = 'sessionTimeoutCountdown';
    var redirectAfter = 10 //read session timeout value from web.config
    var redirectAfterPause = 2000; //# of milliseconds to show expiredMessage before redirting to redirectTo
    var redirectTo = myRedirectUrl; // URL to relocate the user to once they have timed out
    var keepAliveURL = '/'; // URL to call to keep the session alive
    var expiredMessage = 'Your session has expired.  You are being logged out for security reasons.'; // message to show user when the countdown reaches 0
    var running = false; // var to check if the countdown is running
    var timer; // reference to the setInterval timer so it can be stopped
    var stayButton = 'Continue' //Text on button to stay on current page
    var leaveButton = 'Exit' //text on button to take user to the redirectTo page

    $(document).ready(function () {
            // create the warning window and set autoOpen to false
            var sessionTimeoutWarningDialog = $("#sessionTimeoutWarning");
            $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).html(initialSessionTimeoutMessage);
            $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).dialog({
                    title: 'Session Expiration Warning',
                    autoOpen: false,  // set this to false so we can manually open it
                    closeOnEscape: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    width: 460,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    modal: true,

                    beforeClose: function () { // bind to beforeclose so if the user clicks on the "X" or escape to close the dialog, it will work too
                            // stop the timer
                            clearInterval(timer);

                            // stop countdown
                            running = false;

                            // ajax call to keep the server-side session alive
                            $.ajax({
                                    url: keepAliveURL,
                                    async: false
                            });
                    },
                    buttons: {
                            'keep-alive-button' : {
                                    text: stayButton,
                                    click : function () {
                                            // close dialog
                                            $(this).dialog('close');
                                    }
                            },
                            'sign-out-button' : {
                                    text: leaveButton,
                                    click : function () {
                                            // close dialog
                                            window.location = redirectTo;
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    resizable: false,
                    open: function () {
                                    // scrollbar fix for IE
                                    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    },
                    close: function () {
                                    // reset overflow
                                    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                    }
            }); // end of dialog


            // start the idle timer
            $.idleTimer(idleTime);

            // bind to idleTimer's idle.idleTimer event
            $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function () {
                    // if the user is idle and a countdown isn't already running
                    if ($.data(document,'idleTimerObj').idle === true && !running) {
                            var counter = redirectAfter;
                            running = true;

                            // intialisze timer
                            $('#' + sessionTimeoutCountdownId).html(redirectAfter);
                            // open dialog
                            $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).dialog('open');

                            // create a timer that runs every second
                            timer = setInterval(function () {
                                    counter -= 1;

                                    // if the counter is 0, redirect the user
                                    if (counter === 0) {
                                            $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).html(expiredMessage);
                                            setTimeout(function () {
                                                    $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).dialog('disable');
                                                    window.location = redirectTo;
                                            }, redirectAfterPause);
                                    } else {
                                            $('#' + sessionTimeoutCountdownId).html(counter);
                                    };
                            }, 1000);
                    };
            });

    });


</script>
```

In HTML file add:

```
<div id="sessionTimeoutWarning" style="display: none"></div>
```

This opens the dialog box but doesn't force user to visit that page. So the session might expire without user realizing. How to avoid such a behavior?

Comment: Paste some code here regarding what you have tried!!

Comment: Try `window.location.href` or just `location.href` and what will be your `myRedirectUrl`?

Comment: myRedirectUrl is an internal url which is being handled appropriately in the application.

Comment: check the `console` and log `myRedirectUrl` once and see `url` is being passed properly or not?? and also try with what I said in previous comment!

Comment: All the actions are happening properly. My requirement is that when the dialog box pops up irrespective of where the user is currently, he should be taken to this page and asked to perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `window.parent.location`

**EDIT**

```
    $(sessionTimeoutWarningDialog).dialog('disable');
           window.parent.location = redirectTo; //change it here
    }, redirectAfterPause);
```

Since you want to redirect your page through `pop up` this will help you targeting the `pop up's` parent which is the base `window`

Comment: A little more lead into how to use it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I tried and this isn't changing anything.